# Прибавить к отправленному времени определенное кол-во часов (discord)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Пытаюсь написать бота который к отправленному времени прибавит заранее написанное время. Например:
Test 18:00 и после этого бот прибавляет 3 часа и отправляет это в чат т.е Test 18:00 - 21:00.

```
@bot.command()
async def Test (ctx, amount=1):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
    author = ctx.message.author
    await ctx.send(f'Test  {} - {p}')
p = datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(hours=6))
def get_time(p):
    return datetime.datetime.now(p).time().replace(microsecond=0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то идёт текущее время, потом новое и всё в одной строке

```
@bot.command()
async def Test (ctx, time_: str):
    current_datetime = None
    try:
        current_datetime = datetime.strptime(time_, '%H:%M')
    except ValueError:
        return await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} Вы неверно указали время. Пример: 15:00")
    new_datetime = current_datetime + datetime.timedelta(hours=6)
    await ctx.send(f'Test  {current_datetime} - {new_datetime}')
```

Comment: Немного может не так описал, первое время должно быть не текущее, а то которое написал я, т.е например сейчас реальное время 21:30, а в чат я написал Test 15:00 и бот должен отправить сообщение в ответ Test 15:00 - 21:00

Comment: А причём тут тогда реальное время? Что вы вообще хотите сделать?

Comment: Да сейчас посмотрел, забыл убрать это с другой команды, мне нужно не реальное время, а то которое я напишу в чат и к этому времени прибавится +6 часов

Comment: Исправил, в след. раз пишите подробнее